# AngularJS - how to pass a scope variable to a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angular-http

This is my controller, in which I have a variable that I want to use in my service, in order to access some JSON data from the server.

Parts of the controller where I:

1) get the API key from the server (works and logs a key into the console):

```
AuthenticationService.getData()
        .then(function(result) {
            $scope.apiKey = result;
            console.log($scope.apiKey);
    });
```

2) Want to pass the key to service, in order to access data:

```
 DrawService.getData($scope.apiKey)
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.numbers = result.data;
        console.log($scope.numbers);
});
```

Services:

```
app.factory('AuthenticationService', function($http) {
        return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/start/?token=someNumber&sessionId=someNumber')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
            }
        );
    }
}


app.factory('DrawService', function($http) {
            return {
                getData: function(apiKey) {
                var key = apiKey;
                console.log(key);    
                return $http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/draw/?token='+apiKey)
                    .then(function(result) {
                        return result.data;
            });
        }
    }
```

*someNumber* is a number that was provided to me, no mistake there.
*myWebsite.com* is a website example from where I want to get the JSON data.

So, how can I pass the $scope.apiKey to the service without it returning undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `DrawService.getData` method when you get response from the `AuthenticationService.getData()`, That simply means that you should call the DrawService method when you have `apiKey`

```
AuthenticationService.getData()
  .then(function(result) {
    $scope.apiKey = result;
    console.log($scope.apiKey);
     DrawService.getData($scope.apiKey)
       .then(function(result) {
         $scope.numbers = result.data;
         console.log($scope.numbers);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So to be clear, you *can* pass $scope variables to services - the issue here is you're trying to access $scope.apiKey before the APIkey is being returned to you from the Authentication Service. To ensure the data is resolved before using it, simply call your DrawService within the `.then()` of your AuthenticationService.